# Firebase iterate snapshot in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase

I have this code in my app:

```
DataService.dataService.USERS_REF.childByAppendingPath(DataService.dataService.CURRENT_USER_ID).childByAppendingPath("groups").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

  print(snapshot)

})
```

If I print the result, I only get a snapshot with this value:

```
Snap (groups) {
    "-KBAX-d4UNQMZErrTqPD" = true;
    "-KBAX0rrrR-trRZc408F" = true;
    "-KBAX2-lrGd-Bx2zVizv" = true;
    "-KBCL_xUjm-kf1JsGgpA" = true;
    "-KBCOlullSmzi46ecf9J" = true;
}
```

If I print snapshot.key I get

```
groups
```

and if I print snapshot.value I get

```
{
    "-KBAX-d4UNQMZErrTqPD" = true;
    "-KBAX0rrrR-trRZc408F" = true;
    "-KBAX2-lrGd-Bx2zVizv" = true;
    "-KBCL_xUjm-kf1JsGgpA" = true;
    "-KBCOlullSmzi46ecf9J" = true;
}
```

Is there a way to iterate through all the snapshot values and get all the keys and values of each one? In this case, there are 5 keys and values in this snap.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I already found the solution. In this case:

```
DataService.dataService.USERS_REF.childByAppendingPath(DataService.dataService.CURRENT_USER_ID).childByAppendingPath("groups").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

    for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FDataSnapshot] {
        print(rest.key)
    }
})
```